# java.util.logging remove all log file at tomcat startup

Tags: logging, configuration, java.util.logging

when I restart my Tomcat, java.util.logging remove all existing file instead of append.

How can I avoid it?
How I can append to exsisting file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) included with java.util.logging does not delete log files.  It can only rename, [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean)), and truncate.  If the files are being deleted then there is code outside of java.util.logging that is removing the log files.  Install a SecurityManager with all permissions enabled and then turn on [java.security.debug](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/envvars-138887.html#gbmuf) tracing to determine if code running in the JVM deleting the log files.